# Como devolver una entidad con enum

Tags: swift, swift3, enum

Que tal a todos.
Estoy intentando devolver una entidad con un enum, no una tuple.

Actualmente ya he devuelto excepciones pero mi intención es tener entidades por defectos, debido a q son pocas.

Hago esto para devolver una excepción con enum.

```
enum EXCEPTION: String, Error {
            case REGISTER_TYPE = "You need register other type, example BANCA"
            case LIST_ERROR = "You list index not exists"
}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente haciendo que tu enum implemente el protocolo `Error`, ya puedes utilizarlo para lanzar excepciones.

Por ejemplo:

```
func someFunction() throws {
    if someCondition { 
        throw EXCEPTION.REGISTER_TYPE
    }
}
```

Dicha función luego la podrías usar con un bloque try catch así:

```
do {
    try someFunc()
}
catch let error as EXCEPTION {
   print(error) //REGISTER_TYPE
   print(error.rawValue) //You need register other type, example BANCA
}
```

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es que mi enum, me devuelva un modelo como Pet(nombre: "fido", edad: 12)

Comment: Edita tu pregunta con lo que quieres conseguir, porque no queda claro.
Necesitas que los nombres puedan ser variables? Porque si es así, lo suyo es que te declares un struct, no un enum...
Define un poco mejor lo que esperas conseguir, aunque sea con pseudocódigo